# Find out where sql server connections are being left open in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I inherited a ton of C# dotnet code that apparently in some place is not closing the connection or something to sql server and I get

`The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool: This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached`

This happens quite a bit and usually at the same time but I don't know of anything that is scheduled. Also searching manually every little place in code is quite not possible. Any ideas how to fix this without manually going over every single function in the code?

Comment: This can also be a symptom of long-running queries. Check server-side activity.

Comment: You probably don't need to go over every single function in the code, just the data access code and code which uses this. Are you using an ORM ? If so, which one ?

Comment: You mean like entity framework? @sh1rts

Comment: @DanGuzman with spwho2 or something like that?

Comment: @TalC, yes `sp_who2` will report server-side connections from the app. I see from your other comment that you see hundreds of sleeping connections. If the `Last Batch` time is over a couple of minutes old, that indicates connections are not being closed properly. In that case `using` blocks are your friend. If the times are recent, that suggests a recent spike in activity, probably correlating the the connection pool error. Query and index tuning may help in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with not wanting to go through the code is that it's very likely that it's not a single instance or area and may depend on where you're getting the most traffic in the production environment. You could have a fairly innocuous looking query that could be improved slightly with a `.AsNoTracking()` or a better join/include rather than a single big query that is poorly optimized. There are also instances where the entire design is flawed (I came into a project once where sql connections were attached to individual classes, so there was no real way to wrap the connection in a `using` statement. We had to restructure all of it.

If you're using custom transactions or sql connection requests, make sure you're wrapping with a using and a `try catch finally` with a dispose. Relying on the garbage collector is not always great since there's not guarantee the garbage collector whill actually `dispose` immediately at the end of a `using` statement.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    try
    {
        // Transactions, SQL Commands, etc
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // Trans rollback, error handling
    }
    finally
    {
        // Tell the garbage collector to clean up this resource now.
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you're strictly using a database context, some statements can be optimized marginally by using `.AsNoTracking()` for instances where you are only retrieving a result-set but have no intention of modifying the results from that query. Something like the following:

```
var tier = _dbContext.Tier.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(t => t.NameSchema)
    .Include(t => t.TierPackageGroups)
    .Where(t => t.TierNumber == tierNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

Make sure you're using joins or `.Include` wherever possible as opposed to lazy loading.

It's not the answer that you want to hear, and I've been in your shoes, but most likely the *best* solution is to go through the code. You could always start by cleaning up a few areas, gauging impact, a few more areas, gauging impact, etc. This sort of creep investigation can help narrow your search as you see improvements in some areas or don't see some in others.

If you're convinced it has to be a single query that you want to find, then there are tools for evaluating sql performance, but I usually pull in a DBA to handle that so I'm not familiar with those tools. If you're using Azure there is a panel where you can see the queries and have them organized by performance impact. It's not going to point you to the code, but it could give you a hint.

Since the question is specifically for a solution that doesn't require searching for code, the one other answer that will work is to just throw more hardware at the problem, but this a poor stop-gap that can be costly and ultimately just be delaying the problem or only solving for the problem 99% of the time (until you hit a peak traffic period, for instance). One client we had a few years back has probably spent more than $50k in additional hosting costs when they could've had us fix the issue for under $5k at the time of the initial request.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the issue with searching manually is basically like saying Google has an issue with db pool timeouts... go look in the code and fix it.... I'd first have to isolate where it came from as looking in the whole code is kind of difficult for one person to do. I do agree hardware is not the answer here. I also know about closing connections, and most of them look ok. Also, thanks I'll look into this .Include and some of the code you provided as I'm not familiar.

Comment: I did see however that spwho2 has hundreds of sleeping connections, any idea if this means anything?

Comment: The more obvious answer is connections that aren't closed properly, but this can be misleading. Those connections could be from dropped requests if you have queries that are taking too long and people are refreshing the page, it could also be due to threading issues. Unfortunately the best answer I have for you is to chip away at the code based on my personal experience. Daunting? yes, but it's the only method I've had consistent results with.

Comment: I've searched for everywhere I could think of in the code with no luck, maybe at a certain time in the day we need more than 100 pooled connections? At what point would I need more than that? Is it if 100 users try to enter the same db server or the same db on that db server? I don't want to just throw more connections at the thing without know what the root cause/solution is.

Comment: In my experience you most likely don't need more connections and there is a query that's slowing things down / timing out / not closing. Just wondering but do you have any automation running on the database during the window you're experiencing a problem?

Comment: Not that I know of, that was the first thing I thought of. But, from my understanding, if 100 users all try to run a command at the same time it'll crash? Then (not sure if it's related), the whole app starts going slow around the same time and bringing down IIS.

Comment: In theory most queries from a pool should take maybe 100ms to 300ms, so you'd need many, many thousands of users to create that kind of wait state unless you have queries that are taking >60 seconds then sure, exactly 100 users or more could cause that (assuming your request timeout is 60s).